# C2597 illegal reference to non static member

Tags: c++, inheritance

Trying to get this homework figured out and I just keep hitting one wall after another. What I am getting now is the error message:

Error 1 error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'circleType::radius'

I have 2 header files, circleType.h and cylinderType.h and I need to out put results for shipping and painting costs that a user would enter. A little help before I go completely out of my mind ... Thank you.

circle.h

```
class circleType
{
public:
static void setRadius(double r);

double getRadius();
double area();
double circumference();

circleType(double r = 0);

private:
double radius;

};

void circleType::setRadius(double r)
{
if (r >= 0)
{
    radius = r;
}
else
{
    radius = 0;
}
}

double circleType::getRadius() 
{
return radius;
}

double circleType::area() 
{
return 3.1416 * radius * radius;
}

double circleType::circumference() 
{
return 2 * 3.1416 * radius;
}

circleType::circleType(double r)
{
setRadius(r);
}
```

cylinderTyper.h

```
#include "circleType.h"

class cylinderType: public circleType
{
public:
static void setRadius(double r);

static double getRadius();
static double area();
static double circumference();

cylinderType(double r = 0);

private:

double radius;

};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cylinderType.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void enterData(int& cylinderBase,int& cylinerHeight, double& shipCost,     double& paintCost);

int main()
{
cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

int cylinderBase, cylinderHeight;
double sCost, pCost, shipCost, paintCost, volume, area = 0, circumference = 0;

enterData(cylinderBase, cylinderHeight, shipCost, paintCost);

cylinderType::setRadius(cylinderBase + cylinderHeight);
cylinderType::getRadius();
cylinderType::area();
cylinderType::circumference();

cout << "Cost of shipping: $" << circumference * shipCost << endl;

cout << "Cost of painting: $" << area * paintCost << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}

void enterData(int& cylinderBase, int& cylinderHeight, double& shipCost, double& paintCost)
{
cout << "Enter the base size of cylinder: ";
cin >> cylinderBase;
cout << endl;

cout << "Enter the hight size of cylinder: ";
cin >> cylinderHeight;
cout << endl;

cout << "Enter shipping cost per liter: ";
cin >> shipCost;
cout << endl;

cout << "Enter cost of painting per square foot: ";
cin >> paintCost;
cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: You have radius in the base class as well as the derived class: I suspect that's the problem

Comment: The "setRadius" method shouldn't be static.

Comment: There should be no `cylinderType::setRadius` function at all, since a correct version is already inherited from the base class.  Cylinder just needs to perform height handling, and calculate the total area of all surfaces (two faces equal to surface area, and one curved surface which just might be related to the circle circumference somehow).

Comment: [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

It's a very simple rule: static member functions can only access member variables that are static as well. That's because a static function isn't called against a specific object, so object members don't make sense in that context.

In your case, the static function `setRadius` is trying to modify the member variable `radius` which is *not* static. I suspect that you really *don't* want `setRadius` to be a static function.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I have tried the suggestions out but end up with a similar error.

Error 1 error C2352: 'circleType::setRadius' : illegal call of non-static member function

This is my dilemma. I get one or the other error. Line 26 in main.cpp is causing the error:

cylinderType::setRadius(cylinderBase + cylinderHeight);

I've tried some other variations but get one of those two error or get an external link error.

Comment: @Raj static functions are meant to be called using the `class::` syntax, while non-static functions are meant to be called with `object.` or `pointer->` syntax. You need to create an object of the class before you call the non-static member.